# Docker compose up does not restart on reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have successfully created docker containers and they work when loaded using:

```
    sudo docker-compose up -d
```

The yml is as follows:

```
services:

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
    links:
      - node:node

  node:
    build: ./node
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./node:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Am I supposed to create a service for this. Reading the documentation I thought that the containers would reload in restart was set to always.

FYI: the yml is inside a projects directory on the home of the base user: ubuntu.

I tried checking for solutions in stack but could not find anything appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: Do get any exit code?, i.e., maybe the container tries to start but fails?

Comment: Did the docker daemon restart, any errors from the logs of the daemon or containers?

Comment: @BMitch: The docker daemon did restart.

Comment: @Mohammed Noureldin: exit code? Would it be in the logs? Does docker have its own log and if so can you kindly let me know where it would be located. Thanks

Comment: For some reason the containers have loaded on reboot as documented. Thanks

Comment: Exit code: `docker status -a`. The logs are also interesting to check: `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME`.